# android Can't catch custom exception thrown by Invoke

Tags: android, proguard

```
public class HttpProxy{
   public static <T> T getProxy(Class<T> c) {
     return (T) Proxy.newProxyInstance(HttpProxy.class.getClassLoader(),
        new Class<?>[] { c }, handler);

   }

static class HttpInvocationHandler implements InvocationHandler {
@Override
public Object invoke(Object proxy, Method method, Object[] args)
        throws Throwable {


    Object obj = null;
    try {    
        throw new CustomException()
    }catch (CustomException e) {
       //it work here
        throw e;
    } 

    return obj;

  }

 }
}
```

call the method:

```
 try{
      Res resp = HttpProxy.getProxy(IMODEL.class).login();
  if (res != null){
      return ok;
  }
  }  catch (CustomException e) {
  //after set proguard.config ,its didn't work
  Log.e(TAG, Log.getStackTraceString(e));

 } catch(Exception e){
  //after set proguard.config ,its did here
  }
```

If I set project.properties , I can't catch custom exception.

If I don't not set project.properties it works fine.

like this [obfuscation with proguard vs. java.lang.reflect.Proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5797106/obfuscation-with-proguard-vs-java-lang-reflect-proxy/5797433#5797433)